# Adding files to archive

Tags: powershell

I have a script that zips up all files and folders inside a Source folder, and copies them to the Destination folder, then deletes them.
I have added error logging as well.
I am a newbie at Powershell, and although the script works most of the time, some times it does not add the files to the archive, and of course deletes it afterwards so I have no record.
The error logging does not catch this

```
$Log = "c:\support\scripts\CommsLogArchiveDMLog.txt"
$DestZip="D:\SDM\Fltctrl\MsgBackup\"
$Source = "D:\SDM\Fltctrl\Msglog\ANZ\"
$folder = Get-Item -Path $Source
$ZipTimestamp = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd-HHmmss;
$ZipFileName  = $DestZip + $ZipTimestamp + "_Comms" + ".zip" 

$Source
write-output "" >> $Log
write-output $ZipTimestamp >> $Log
Write-output "... Waiting for the zip file to be created" >> $Log
Try
{
    set-content $ZipFileName ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
    while (!(Test-Path -PathType leaf -Path $ZipFileName))
    { 
        Start-Sleep -s 20
    }
}
catch
{
    Write-Output "Ran into an issue: $($PSItem.ToString())" >> $Log
}


Try
{
    $ZipFile = (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace($ZipFileName) 
}
catch
{
    Write-Output "Ran into an issue: $($PSItem.ToString())" >> $Log
}

Write-Output "... Zip file created" >> $Log 
Start-Sleep -s 10

write-output "... Adding files to archive" >> $Log
Try
{
    $ZipFile.CopyHere($Source)
}
catch
{
    Write-Output "Ran into an issue: $($PSItem.ToString())" >> $Log
}

Try
{   
    $ZipFileName
}
catch
{
    Write-Output "Ran into an issue: $($PSItem.ToString())" >> $Log
}

write-output "... Successfully added files to archive" >> $Log

Start-Sleep -s 10

write-output "... Deleting source files" >> $Log
Try
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse -force |
    Where-Object { -not ($_.psiscontainer) } |
    Remove-Item –Force
}
catch
{
    Write-Output "Ran into an issue: $($PSItem.ToString())" >> $Log
}
write-output "... Successfully deleted source files" >> $Log
```

Any suggestions o how to get this working as expected would be much appreciated.
Ideally I would like the files to only be deleted if it has been added to the archive successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using the `Compress-Archive` function. I've never used it before, but it could make your code a little cleaner. Here is what I came up with, but it is untested:

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
param (
    $Source = "D:\SDM\Fltctrl\Msglog\ANZ\",
    $Destination = "D:\SDM\Fltctrl\MsgBackup\",
    $Log = "c:\support\scripts\CommsLogArchiveDMLog.txt"
)

function Log ( [String] $Message ) {
    Write-Verbose -Message $Message
    if ( $Log )
    {
        "$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HHmmss): $Message" | Add-Content $Log
    }
}

# Generate .zip filename
$ArchiveFilePath = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath "$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HHmmss)_Comms.zip"
Log -Message "Destination archive filepath: $ArchiveFilePath"

# Compress files
try
{
    Compress-Archive -Path $Source -DestinationPath $ArchiveFilePath -CompressionLevel Optimal
}
catch
{
    Log -Message "An error occurred creating archive: $($_.ToSTring()) Terminating script."
    throw $_
}

# Remove source files
try
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse -force `
    | Where-Object -Property PSIsContainer -EQ -Value $false `
    | ForEach-Object `
        -Begin { Log -Message "Removing file(s) from $Source"; $Count = 1 } `
        -Process {
            Log -Message "Removing item: $($_.FullName)"
            $_ | Remove-Item -Force
            $Count ++
        } `
        -End { Log -Message "Removed $Count file(s) from $Source" }
}
catch
{
    Log -Message "An error occurred removing files: $($_.ToSTring()) Terminating script"
    throw $_
}
```

Comment: Cheers Shawn, I will test it

Comment: I do not have the Compress-Archive cmdlet installed, and I doubt that I will get it done on our servers

Comment: It looks like I have version 4 installed

Comment: I managed to get Powershell 5 installed on my server, and testing looks good. Thank you Shawn.

Comment: @Jacques no problem. Be sure to mark it as an answer